# Android studio Navigation drawer showing dark screen on design View

Tags: android

I installed Android studio 3.1.3 and it's only showing a dark screen

[image: design View image]

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.herson.freed"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
     implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

It gives this error in gradle:

> "Unable to resolve dependency" error in support-v4:28.0.0-alpha

Please help, I'm still new to Android.

Comment: post your gradle

Comment: @prashant17 i posted my gradle

Comment: change all `alpha3` to `alpha1` and sync project

Comment: @prashant17 it didn't work..still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are connected to a good network

Check this checkbox

> Goto >file -> other settings -> Under build, execution, and deployment
>   -> you will see Gradle. uncheck the checkbox offline work

Try adding Google maven repository into app's build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
```

rebuild your project.

If step 1 won't work, remove gradle from your project root folder and rebuild your project again.

Comment: Check if you are not in offline mode

Comment: Goto >file -> other settings -> Under build, execution, and deployment -> you see see gradle. uncheck checkobx the offline work